# panic:integer divide fault Message Observed on SRX 5800 Routine Engine

Tags: firewall, security, juniper-srx, errors

We are running 2 x Juniper SRX 5800 Firewalls in a cluster environment. Node 0 got rebooted and Node 1 took over the master role. Node 0 came back online after reboot. The reasons for Node 0 to reboot are unclear.

When we run the command 'show chassis routing-engine' we see the message '`panic:integer divide fault'` for Routing Engine in Node 0.

```
node0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hostname: RRR-SSS-FWR-SRX5-1
Model: srx5800
```

### Node0:

```
Routing Engine status:
  Slot 0:
    Current state                  Master
    Election priority              Master (default)
    Temperature                 37 degrees C / 98 degrees F
    CPU temperature             33 degrees C / 91 degrees F
    DRAM                      2048 MB
    Memory utilization          18 percent
    CPU utilization:
      User                       2 percent
      Background                 0 percent
      Kernel                    12 percent
      Interrupt                  4 percent
      Idle                      82 percent
    Model                          RE-S-1300
    Serial ID                      9009057179
    Start time                     2021-05-16 05:00:06 PKT
    Uptime                         5 days, 10 hours, 28 minutes, 39 seconds
    Last reboot reason             panic:integer divide fault
    Load averages:                 1 minute   5 minute  15 minute
                                       0.18       0.19       0.17
```

Is it possible that someone know what this message means? I guess this is a free BSD message.

Can someone give a brief review of what does this means?

Thanks

Comment: Either a sw bug, or a hw memory fault.

Comment: Looks very much like a (cosmetic) bug.